Using the Galleon Wallet I have 2 Delegation Contracts Staking but my Manager Address is inactive
i even tried sending some XTZ to my manager address, and the coins do not show in the wallet.  the wallet currently reads that "Your account is ready to receive transactions" and did so when i sent the test trans to the manager address.  I want to withdraw my tezos, need some help!

Cryptonomic (the makers of Galleon) run their own forum, where they are more active. YOu might be better off asking this question there: https://discourse.cryptonomic.tech/

Not clear with your question...since it has been a while has it been resolved or you still need help?
